# Copy database from sdcard to data/data/packagename/databases/ folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard

In my application I download database from the server through download              manager class and it default storage in 'sdcard', so I want to copy this downloaded data in 'sdcard' to data/data folder. So please any one can help me?

Comment: Have you googled first ?

Answer (score 1):

Try out below function to copy your database from sdcard to your application package.

```
private void exportDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
       FileChannel source=null;
       FileChannel destination=null;
       String currentDBPath = "<your sdcard path>";
       String backupDBPath = "data/data/"+ "<yourpackagename>" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;;
       File currentDB = new File(sd, currentDBPath);
       File backupDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);
       try {
            source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            source.close();
            destination.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Change the `currentDBPath` and  `backupDBPath` according to your database downloaded path and the path where you want to take backup of it.

Comment: backupDB should be replaced with context.getDatabasePath(SAMPLE_DB_NAME)